# Is there a form for the inverse of $(1-l x) ^K(1+w x)^{(T-K)}$ in terms of "named" functions (Beta, Gamma, etc)?

Tags: special-functions, inverse, change-of-variable

Let $l \in (0,1)$, $w>0$, $K$ and $T$ positive integers.

The function $f(x) = (1-l x)^K(1+w x)^{(T-K)}$, restricted to $x \in [0,1]$ is then logconcave in x.
Thus, we can separate the domain into regions where the function is increasing/decreasing.

Let $x^*$ denote the maximum of this function. Then, if $x<x^*$, there is an inverse function $g_{<x^*}(y)$. Analogously, for $x>x^*$, we have the inverse $g_{>x^*}(y)$.

My question: is there a representation of this function in terms of special functions, such as Beta, Gamma, etc?

The context is that I want to do a change of variables inside the integral:

$\int_{0}^1\psi(f(x))dx$

and write it as something like:

$\int_{g_{<x^*}(0)}^{g_{<x^*}(x^*)}\psi(y)g'_{<x^*}(y)dy$ + $\int_{g_{>x^*}(x^*)}^{g_{>x^*}(1)}\psi(y)g'_{>x^*}(y)dy$